# MVC Custom http headers set in web config but not all calls having them set

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-web-api

I have the following tags set in my MVC web application.

```
<system.webServer>  
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
         <remove name="X-Powered-By" />      
         <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
         <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />    
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

In this web application, i also have few web APIs. After this is set, when i inspect the calls in fiddler, the new custom headers show up in response headers for only few calls. Few calls do not have this custom headers set up. It is random. Why is not being set to ALL the traffic in my web application? any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you another web.config file somewhere else ? in area ? in web api project ... ? Another file overritting `customHeaders`. If no try to check your IIS configuration headers